# Skipping over Error?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help:

I have the code beneath that contacts Twitter's API in order to get retweet count from a Twitter ID no.  I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to enter the code so that it skips ID numbers the module (Tweepy) doesnt recognise instead of just stopping altogether?

EDIT: The Error being "TweepError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]"

Thanks!

```
import tweepy


consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = "" 


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

id_list = ["4000000000000",
"etc.....",
]

def get_retweet_count(tweet_id):
    tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id)
    return tweet.retweet_count

for id in id_list:
    print get_retweet_count(id), id
```

Comment: It will help people answer the question if you give them the error traceback

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can use a try/except statement for this…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) -- i.e. put a `try` `except` clause around any code that throws exceptions you think you can handle.

eg.

```
try:
    print get_retweet_count(id)
except TweepError, e:
    print e
    print "carrying on anyway"
```

Answer (score 1):

As thecoder mentioned, a try - except block should solve the problem:

```
for id in id_list:
    try:
        print get_retweet_count(id), id
    except:
        pass
```